# Access the order object from woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

In WooCommerce, I am making a custom merchant plugin and I have added this hook:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table', 'track_me' );
```

Inside the `track_me()` function, I want to **retrieve the order** to do some things.

The function does what I want when I want, but I'm currently getting the `order_id` from the URL which seems janky.

I cannot figure out how to properly retrieve the `$order` object or the `$order_id` which would be enough.

It's almost certainly something obvious as hours of searching the Internet has been fruitless. I just don't know what the obvious something is...

UPDATE 1: Following the advice of @LoicTheAztec, I did the following:

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table_items', $order );

class Order_MY extends WC_Order
{
    function __construct() 
    {
        add_action( 'woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table', array( $this, 'track_me' ) );
    }

    function track_me( $order ) 
    { 
        // My code here
    }
}
```

The first place the script fails is on the do_action line where PHP complains $order is an undefined variable.

The script also fails at extending WC_Order: Class 'WC_Order' not found

New question... is there something I need to do to make sure I have access to the woocommerce classes in my plugin?

Answer (score 0):

The `WC_Order` Object instance **`$order`** variable is included in the hook. 
You see that on [`order/order-details.php` template file](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/order/order-details.php#L76) *(line 76)*:

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table_items', $order );
```

So you can use it in your hooked function this way:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table', 'track_me' );

function track_me( $order ) {

     // The Order ID
     $order_id = $order->get_id();

     // your code goes below
}
```

Now in a plugin, **inside a class**, you will replace:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table', 'track_me' );
```

by:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table', array( $this, 'track_me' ) );
```

---

**Addition:**

As you can't get the $order object from your plugin you should also try:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table', 'track_me' );

function track_me( $order ) {

     if ( ! is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) {
         global $order;
     }

     // The Order ID
     $order_id = $order->get_id();

     // your code goes below
}
```

I cant tell you anything more

Comment: I think the part I'm getting lost on is the inside a class part. My plugin doesn't have a class (at the moment, though I did try that). If I create a class, MY_WC_Order to extend WC_Order, how does that interact with the action hook?

Comment: If your plugin doesn't use OOP and haven't a class, just use `add_action( 'woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table', 'track_me' );` … What version of WooCommerce do you use?

Comment: Woo is v 3.7.0. I tried it without the class first, that didn't work either. I get the error that $order is undefined. When I look at $order in the globals it's not an object and its contents are just 'DESC' so I think the variable $order gets redefined somewhere else. I was digging around in another third-party plugin that has access to the $order_id but I can't figure out how it does it.

Comment: @JessycaFrederick as you can see on the template, the $order variable is include for this hook, so I don't know what you tell you more…  I have added an addition in my answer, but I am not sure that is going to solve this issue.

Comment: thank you so much. There's some fundamental concept I don't understand, but my hack works, so I'll stick with it for now until I learn enough to figure out what I'm doing wrong ;)

Answer (score -1):

I am not an expert but maybe sth. like this could work:

```
global $order_id;
$order = wc_get_order($order_id);
```

Comment: $order_id is not an available global variable.